# Virtual Box Doesn't Free Up Storage After Deleting .vdi File

Tags: virtualbox

After I uninstalled my VM, I selected "Delete All Files", the drive was 25GB so I should've had 25GB freed, but it was still at 78GB for my total storage when I should have 100+GB. I've tried WinDirStat but it can't find the large file. I've tried restarting in case it was just a bug, didn't work. I even checked the Recycling bin to see if it got stored there but it wasn't.

Comment: Was it created from a linked clone?

Comment: No, it wasn't created from a linked clone.

Comment: I don't know anything about WinDirStat, but VirtualBox won't delete a disk file that's "in use by" (i.e. attached to) another VM, running or not. Did you check File > Virtual Media Manager in VirtualBox? Was it indeed 25GB, or was it Dynamically allocated with a *maximum* of 25GB?

Comment: It wasn't in the Media Manager and it was Dynamic.